# Problem identifying type of equation (linear/nonlinear)

Tags: continuum-mechanics, non-linear-systems, linear-systems

I've looked at the answer to this Math.SE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/414597/), but I still can't know the answer to my question here.

The following is the equation of equilibrium: divergence of stress tensor that is the sum of mechanical stress and Maxwell stress.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_j} \left[L_{ijkl}(X) \frac{\partial u_k}{\partial X_l}(X) + M_{ijkl}(X) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial X_k}(X) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial X_l}(X) \right] = 0$$

where $X$ is the position variable, $L$ is the elasticity tensor, $u$ is the displacement vector field, $M$ is the electrostriction tensor, and $\varphi$ is the electric potential.

Since $\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial X_l}$ is multiplied by a tensor (elasticity tensor) which is not a scalar, so the equation becomes nonlinear in the displacement? And also for the electric potential, it is multiplied by the electrostriction tensor and also multiplied again with the partial derivative of the partial derivative of itself, so does that make it nonlinear in electric potential as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the equation is written in your case, although the elasticity tensor field is position dependent, it does not depend on the displacement field or its derivatives, so the equation is linear in the displacement field. However, you are correct that the equation is nonlinear in electric potential, since it contains products of the field derivatives.